# Firebase show missing dSYMs - Unable to see crash on Firebase Crashlytics

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I have two iOS apps, 1 - migrated from Fabric to Firebase. 2- On boarded in Firebase; Both  apps  show missing required dSYM message on the Firebase dashboard. I have tried uploading the dSYM and in most cases, it takes longer than 12 hours to process and get the crashes on the Firebase dashboard.

I am using Fabric legacy SDK and downloading the dSYM for Apple. Is there any outages or glitches with Firebase Crashlytics that I am not aware of ?

Answer (score 1):

According to Firebase Support;

Currently, it is taking (around) 24 hr to process the dSYMs (specially, if dSYM size is large).

Most Impacted Developers:

- Fabric legacy only, not migrated customers - Should no see any impact
- Fabric legacy SDK, migrated to Firebase - Impacted.
- Fabric legacy SDK, onboarded via Firebase - Impacted.
- Firebase SDK (currently in beta) - Not impacted.

It is suspected that the dsym downloaded from Apple has the incorrect bundle id. Apple is setting com.apple.xcode.dsym. (e.g. com.apple.xcode.dsym.Bingo Blast).

Temporary Solution;

1. As a temporary workaround, if the developer after downloading the
   dsym from Apple, converted all occurrences of the incorrect bundle
   string with the correct bundle id (e.g. com.redhotlabs.bingo), this
   should allow the dsym to be ingested correctly.

See an example shell script that developers could use replacing the and with the appropriate values.

export BUNDLE_ID='' 
export DSYM_PATH='' 
sed -i '' -e "s/>com.apple.xcode.dsym.*\$BUNDLE_ID\

2. Try not test-crash the app or release a potentially crashy app to
   users for at least 10 minutes after upload-symbols has completed and
   the mapping file is uploaded.
3. Recommending to upgrade to Firebase SDK (currently in beta) to avoid
   this issue all to gather.

Comment: Tried this and after 7 hours dSyms are NOT shown yet. I guess we have to wait more?

Comment: Konstantinos Natsios - Are you still having issue processing the dSYM

Comment: nope we managed to do it with fabric key instead of GSP with the script.